# How to get the class of an input inside a jQuery each loop?

Tags: jquery, loops

I have function which appends inputs inside a list item when a link is clicked. I then loop through these inputs using an each loop using the code below. It is working correctly as shown, however instead of using field.name I want to use the class of the input as the array key but when i try to do this the class is shown as undefined.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
var values = {};
$.each($('li :input').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

Here is the code I have inside the list item once I have appended the hidden inputs using jQuery append:

```
<li><input type="hidden" name="group" class="group" value="2"/><input type="hidden" name="condition" class="condition" value="isany"/><input type="hidden" name="value" class="value" value="1,2"/></li>
```

I can get the name attribute fine but class is always undefined.

Could anybody help with this?

Comment: how're you trying to get the classname?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
var values = {};
$('li :input').each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

This work when I tested.

```
var values = {};
$('li input').each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).val();
});
alert(JSON.stringify(values));
```

Comment: `values[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).val();`

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and it works for the name attribute but when i try for class attribute which is what I want then it still returns class as undefined

Comment: Hi, here is what i have appended inside the list item: 

`<li><input type="hidden" name="group" class="group" value="2"/><input type="hidden" name="condition" class="condition" value="isany"/><input type="hidden" name="value" class="value" value="1,2"/></li>`

I can get the name attribute but not the class

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out how to get it to work with $.serializeArray, but this works. (change `console.log` to `$("body").append` if you don't have a console).

`$.each($('input'),function(){console.log(this.className)})`

Note that you use the native javascript `this` rather than the jquery object `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = {};
$.each($('li :input').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[$(field).attr('class')] = field.value;
});
```